# Why do these functions truncate the return value?

Tags: c++, function, arithmetic-expressions, truncated

## Beware there be Homework below.

## Edits:

Took out useless information.

So obviously this is a homework assignment everything seems correct besides the calculations inside my functions.

How do I return a non truncated value?

```
float hat(float weight, float height) {
    return (weight/height)*2.9;
}
float jacket(float weight, float height, int age) {
    double result = (height * weight) / 288;
    /*now for every 10 years past 30 add (1/8) to the result*/
    if((age - 30) > 0){
        int temp = (age - 30) / 10;
        result = result + (temp * .125);
        //cout<<"result is: "<<result<<endl;
    }
    return result;
}

float waist(float weight, int age) {
    double result = weight / 5.7;
    /*now for every 2 years past 28 we add (1/10) to the result*/
    if((age - 28) > 0){
        int temp = (age - 28) / 2;
        result = result + (temp * .1);
    }
return result;}
```

Comment: You're taking inputs in the wrong order. Learn to use a debugger

Comment: I just figured that out. Now the values are truncating down or up to the nearest value. I'm going to update this question.

Comment: There's a *reason* we ask for [minimal complete examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: For a homework question yours isn't **that** bad, but you have provided too much detail. People have other things to do besides reading through the intricate details of your homework assignment. Boil it down to the essentials - you are taking an input, and you're having trouble calculating and/or displaying the output. Write a new program that does **just** that. If you have the same problem after that, post **that** code for people to look at.

Comment: Ok so In this case I should cut out all everything that does not have to do with truncating values. Got it.

Comment: You have to set "fixed" once before you use setprecision(int)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `fixed`:

```
  // Output data //
  cout << fixed;
  cout << "hat size: " << setprecision(2) << hat(weight, height) << endl;
  cout << "jacket size: " << setprecision(2) << jacket(weight, height, age) << endl;
  cout << "waist size: " << setprecision(2) << waist(weight, age) << endl;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
cout << "hat size: " << setprecision(2) << hat(weight, height) << endl;
```

You've tripped over a gotcha in the way iostreams formatted output works.

In the "default" mode for formatting floating point values (not having requested `fixed` or `scientific` output), the precision is the *total* number of digits to print, *on both sides of the decimal point*.  Think "significant figures", not "number of fractional digits".

For what you are trying to do, I suggest you either use "fixed" mode or round by hand and then don't specify a precision.